# CSV Reader works, Trouble with CSV writer

Tags: csv, python-3.6, writer

I am writing a very simple python script to READ a CSV (no problem) and to write to another CSV (issue):

System info:

- Windows 10
- Powershell
- Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

### Sample Data: [Office Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPPwZ.png)

The purpose is to filter events based on criteria, and to write to another CSV with desired criteria.

For Example:

I would like to read from this CSV and write the events where Registrations (or column 4) is Greater than 0 (remove rows with registrations = 0)

```
# SCRIPT TO FILTER EVENTS TO BE PROCESSED

import os
import time
import shutil
import os.path
import fnmatch
import csv
import glob
import pandas


# Location of file containing ALL events
path = r'allEvents.csv'

# Writes to writer
writer = csv.writer(open(r'RegisteredEvents' + time.strftime("%m_%d_%Y-%I_%M_%S") + '.csv', "wb"))
writer.writerow(["Event Name", "Start Date", "End Date", "Registrations", "Total Revenue", "ID", "Status"])
#writer.writerow([r'Event Name', r'Start Date', r'End Date', r'Registrations', r'Total Revenue', r'ID', r'Status'])
#writer.writerow([b'Event Name', b'Start Date', b'End Date', b'Registrations', b'Total Revenue', b'ID', b'Status'])

def checkRegistrations(file):
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)
    for row in data:
       #if row[3] > str(0):
        if row[3] > int(0):
            writer.writerow(([data]))
```

The Error I continue to get is:

```
    writer.writerow(["Event Name", "Start Date", "End Date", "Registrations", "Total Revenue", "ID", "Status"])
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have tried using the various commented out statements

For Example:

- "" vs r"" **vs** r'' **vs** b''
- `if row[3] > int(0) **vs** if row[3] > str(0)`

Every time I execute my script, It creates the file.. so the first csv writer line works (create and open the file)... the second line (to write the headers) is when the error appears...

Perhaps I am getting mixed up with syntax due to python versions, or perhaps I am misusing the CSV library, or (more than likely) I have endless to learn about data type IO and conversion... someone please help!!

I am aware of the excess of import libraries -- script came from another basic script to move files from one location to another based on filename and output a rowcounter for each file being moved.
With that being said, I may be unaware of any missing/ needed libraries

Please let me know if you have any questions, concerns or clarifications
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry Forgot to add last line of code to execute defined function (not that it really matters considering error happening before point of function call)


        ** checkRegistrations(path)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'wb'))
```

The 'wb' argument is the [file mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). The 'b' means that you are opening the file that you are writing to in binary mode. You are then trying to write a string which isn't what it is expecting.

Try getting rid of the 'b' in the 'wb'.

```
writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w'))
```

Let me know if that works for you.